# javascript files do not work or get uploaded nodejs express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

Well, the problem is: though I declared static folder for my application as `app.use(express.static('public'))` and have files from this folder successfully loaded by browser, my script from below screenshot doesn't load at all

[image: page inspector]

There's actually no difference whether I put address with or without dot in front of it, it just never loads. What might be wrong here?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a useful description of the problem. Do you get a 404 error? Do you get the wrong content? Does the script load fine but then the JS  not do what you want? Are any errors displayed on the Console?

Comment: @Quentin it doesn't show any error message in console. I tried to execute console.log in the first line of my script and log string didn't appear neither in browser nor server. As for styles file, it has "Open in source tab' in its context menu, but this script does not

Comment: Use the Network tab. See exactly what response you get from the server.

Comment: When I click Open In new Tab it does actually show me the script, but it seems that it doesn't get loaded or executed in the page

Comment: @Quentin there's no request for script file :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value of the `type` attribute is one that the browser does not recognise, then it will not attempt to load the script. (Why would it? It has been told it is in a language it can't work with.)

The **default** value for a `type` attribute on a `<script>` element is `text/javascript`. If that is the value you want then providing it explicitly is a waste of time and an opportunity to type the wrong value and break your page.

This is what you have done.

**Omit the type attribute**